# Unable to generate PDF with A/3 compliance when font-awesome icons (PUA unicodes) are used (missing actualText)

Tags: html, pdf, unicode, puppeteer

We are using puppeteer to generate a PDF from a HTML template, when this template contains font-awesome icons it fails the validation to PDF-A/3 standards.

*Step to reproduce:*

(1) Set an HTML template/file with font-awesome icons that uses unicode in the PUA (Private Use Areas) range :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"/>
    <style>
      body {background-color: white !important }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <span class="fas fa-comment"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

(2) Print as PDF in chrome or generate a PDF from puppeteer.

(3) Try to pass PDF-A/3 validation using online or desktop tools.

*What is the expected result?*

Expected results is that the span generated has attribute "actualText" set in the generated PDF.

*What happens instead?*

No "actualText" is set, and thus according to this rule https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Parts-2-and-3-rules#rule-621173-1 making the validation to fail. (see attachment).

There is a weird behavior, if you use the "fa-check" icon (still in the PUA range), the validation passes because an "actualText" has been set in the generated PDF (see PDF content for this use-case in attachment below). Why is that? This should be the standard output for every PUA unicode.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Done, i just updated my post.

Comment: Just an update, I opened a thread on chromium : you can see what they have to say about it here : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1484941